# D3D12 Dynamic Constant Buffer Creation and Binding

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-12

I'm writing a shader tool app where I can create nodes and link them to generate a texture:

[image: Shader Tool]

I used D3D12 shader reflection to get the constant buffer variables and now I'm trying to figure out how to pass/bind these vars in runtime. At the moment I have the constant buffers defined in code like this:

```
struct ObjectConstants
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 World{ D3DUtil::Identity4x4() };
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 Color{ 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };
};
```

How can I create a constant buffer, bind it and copy data from CPU to GPU in runtime?

PS: The root signature and PSO are being created in runtime.

Comment: It depends on exactly what is in your root signature (see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/resource-binding-in-hlsl#constant-buffers)). As for creating the CB data, typically it's done in an UPLOAD heap and you fence it per-frame. See [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12) and the ``GraphicsMemory`` class.

Comment: Do you know how to create a constant buffer in d3d12 (in general), and only need to know how to do it for this specific use case?